# Aligning :after element with vertical tabs

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

this is my first post here and I feel dumb for asking the question. It should be simple but I just can't get the alignment working.

I'm trying to add a triangle to the right of the tabs (similar to https://www.libs.uga.edu/), and I can get the triangle but can't get it to responsively align to the right of the active vertical tab. Currently the triangle is displaying on the next line. I can hardcode the positioning, but as the screen size changes it moves around. Am I missing something obvious? I also can't tell if the Foundation cell is throwing me off, as it's my first time using Foundation (using JointsWP specifically) but the pen is doing the same thing as the site.

The CSS I'm using is the following:

```
#main-search-tabs{
  position:relative;
}

li.is-active::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-top:20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
  border-left:20px solid green;
}
```

And here's a pen of what I'm doing: https://codepen.io/btailz/pen/pooxvMY
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Realized it worked better if I used the li > a instead of the div and li. Updated the pen to reflect the change. https://codepen.io/btailz/pen/pooxvMY

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).